# Is there a way to avoid increase the images size when I use Display size for accessibility?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm checking the accessibility in my app, using the Display size to increase the font but the images are increasing too. Is there a way to avoid increasing the images?

I just need to increase the text size.

This is the layout, my goal is only the accessibility increase the text

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:textAlignment="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
            tools:ignore="contentDescription"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text3" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you specify their size in sp?  If so, don't do that (you want dp).  Otherwise that won't happen.

Comment: The other way you can get this is if you use Relative or ConstraintLayout and put rules on the image views that make its size/position relative to the text views.  In that case, break the linkage.  But we can't help with that without your full layout.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm using dp, and I updated my question with the layout content. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I inflate your layout (after adding some `android:text` and a `android:src`) on a Google Pixel device running Android 9, and then change **Settings -> Display -> [Advanced -> ] Font size**, I can not see the problem you describe. The text size is changed, but the image size is the same.

**However**, due to the top `TextView`, the image gets shifted down, which can be perceived as a change in its size, especially if the top `TextView` happens to be hidden behind an App Bar.

So the answer to this question is "Your layout works fine, you just perceive there to be a problem when there isn't".

If you can still reproduce the problem, please show us screenshots of before and after a change in system **Font size**, which might help us debug the problem further. Also specify what device and Android version you use, as well as any additional code that might be relevant.

Comment: thanks for answer. I check the app using an Emulator Pixel 3 Api 29, there I can see how the image change its size. I tried to run the app in a Samsung device running Android 9, the image doesn't change. I think only happens with Emulators.

Comment: I just tried on Pixel 3 API 29 emulator and I can not reproduce the problem there either. The texts changes size but the drawable does not change size. Can you please add before-and-after screenshots from Pixel 3 API 29 emulator to your question so I can take a look? Thanks!
Btw, what drawable are you using? Normal .png drawable? Or some vector graphics drawable? Can you share it so I can try with it? Wouldn't hurt to specify what texts you are using either.